# my choices over javascript framework and javascript UI libraries

Tags: javascript

I heard many people say if you're looking for a Javascript UI library to be used with jQuery, it's best to go for jQuery UI.
My question here is: is there any other combinational option for me for other javascript frameworks apart from jQuery and js ui libraries to recommend? I just would like to explore more in their ui enhancement capabilities and that can definitely be my alternative ways in web development.

any advice would be really much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

MooTools is quite elegant. see http://mootools.net/